# How do magnetic dipoles align with external magnetic fields?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, magnetic-fields, electrons, magnetic-moment

Based on the equation for energy of a magnetic dipole in an external field: 
$$E=-\mu \cdot B$$ I would have thought that the system would minimise its potential energy and so the $\mu $ will be aligned anti parallel to $B$.

However, in my QM course we were talking about the spin angular momentum aligning with the external magnetic field.

Why is this so?

Comment: Why do you say that $\mu$ being anti-parallel to $B$ would give it less energy than if $\mu$ were parallel to $B$?

Comment: Ah my bad i just realised if it were parallel $E=-\mu B$ and so it would be the most negative and hence lowest when parallel, so is this why the electrons magnetic moment tries to align with external $B$
 fields?

Comment: Well, using your own argument, that configuration is the minimum of the potential energy, and so $\mu$ tends to align with $B$ to minimise it.

Comment: @VishalJain No, it is the other way around. The behavior of the dipole is why there is a minus sign in the formula.

Comment: Electrons have spin up and spin down and 2 electrons per orbital so one is up and the other is down, one is with the field and the other is against the field and we have diamagnetism but when we have a single electron in the last orbital then we have paramagnetism and it is typically aligned with the field. Some electrons however will be aligned against the field with the external field strength determining the energy gap between up and down, this can be used for electron spin spectroscopy. but i am not a physicist

Comment: @Pieter I am a bit confused now, what orientation are you saying is most preferential? I wouldve thought that an electron is equally likely to be spin up as spin down. If any 1 is more preferential than the other wouldnt we see an asymmetry?